# Printing string, not amount of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do work, as I am a brand new coder. Well I have not learnt that much so I am doing basic codes.
I am using a random variable to print the string that comes with the variable, not the amount of characters in the string.

Sorry if anyone gets annoyed but I cannot seem to find the solution to this problem anywhere, and if there is one I must be entering the wrong search

Thank you in advance.

**Code:**

```
import random

EFile=open("ExternalFile.txt","w+")
Info1=EFile.write("Shotgun - George Ezra")
Info2=EFile.write("God's Plan - Drake")
Info3=EFile.write("This is me - Kiara Settle")
Info4=EFile.write("Solo - Clean Bandit")
Info5=EFile.write("Psyco - Post Malone")
EFile.close

Array=[Info1, Info2, Info3, Info4, Info5]


Efile=open("ExternalFile.txt","r")

RanVar=random.choice(Array)
print(RanVar)
```

I want it to print the string, that is in the brackets, but it prints the amount of characters and I cannot understand why.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Lord Doe. Are you trying to print `Array`?

Comment: Yes, I am but instead of it printing the words, it prints the characters.

Comment: You're writing the strings to a file, is that intended? If you just want to print one of the strings randomly, you don't need to write it to a file before printing it.

Comment: Yes, it is intended. I need to have them all in a file and print the variables.

Answer (score 2):

`EFile.write(string)`'s return value is the number of characters written, not what was written. It is also better to store all of what you want to write to the file in a list. I'm also assuming you want to write each song name with a newline. Also, it's not mandatory, but there is no need to capitalize variable names and is against convention.

```
import random

songs = ["Shotgun - George Ezra", "God's Plan - Drake", "This is me - Kiara Settle", "Solo - Clean Bandit", "Psyco - Post Malone"]

efile = open("ExternalFile.txt", "w+")

for song in songs:
    efile.write(song + "\n")

efile.close()

ran_var = random.choice(songs)
print(ran_var)
```

This may be a bit advanced for your skill level, but it's good to use a `with` block for working with files:

```
with open("ExternalFile.txt", "w+") as efile:
    for song in songs:
        efile.write(song + "\n")
```

`with` blocks close the file automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
(...)
Efile=open("ExternalFile.txt","r")
lines_at = random.randrange(0, len(Array))
lines = Efile.readlines()
print(lines[lines_at])
```

This code will works.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

EFile=open("ExternalFile.txt","w+")

Info1=("Shotgun")
Info2=("God's Plan")
Info3=("This is me")
Info4=("Solo")
Info5=("Psyco")

EFile.write(Info1)
EFile.write(Info2)
EFile.write(Info3)
EFile.write(Info4)
EFile.write(Info5)
EFile.close

Array=[Info1, Info2, Info3, Info4, Info5]

RanVar=random.choice(Array)
print(RanVar)
```

I feel this code is more suitable, as further on I will need to split the strings and print just the 1st character of each song name as it is a code guessing game.

This was suggested by Sheldon and I am able to understand and work with it.

Thank you for the help though!

Comment: I **highly** suggest you use a list instead of `Info1`, `Info2`, etc. They are MUCH easier to work with in the long run and prevent the need for writing out every single `EFile.write`, etc. For future projects, using a list is much better than declaring many variables.